# Border-radius applied to single sied border creating "moon" shape instead of semi-circle

Tags: css

How can I turn this into a normal semicircle, without it looking like a moon, and turn the image into a circle instead of an ellipsis?

http://jsfiddle.net/226tq1rb/1/

```
.image{
    width:20%;
    border-radius:500%;
    border-right:60px solid rgba(0,0,250,0.1);
    padding:100px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you want that right border to be a semicircle to the RIGHT of the pic, or with it's straight edge right through the middle of the pic? It's hard to visualize what you're trying to do.

Comment: Semicircle to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, I was "disabling" the top, left, and bottom borders, if I simply change the color to transparent they aren't visible but are technically still there, thus the edges of the border become straight instead of tapering.